# How to require more than whitespace content in XSD?

Tags: regex, xml, xsd, xsd-validation, xml-validation

I've been having problems to develop a regex expression that would allow me to check the following:

Tag text is not:

Empty

```
<TextTag></TextTag>
```

White space

```
<TextTag>    </TextTag>
```

line Break

```
<TextTag>
</TextTag>
```

But at the same time allow any spaces and line breaks in the middle of the text like so:

```
<TextTag>this would 
be an example </TextTag>
```

the closest I've been able to reach was `.*[^\s-].*`but it fails when there is a line break in the middle like the example I gave you.

Do you know how could I do this?

Comment: You may use a regex like `[\s\S]*[^\s-][\s\S]*`, or a more efficient `[\s-]*[^\s-][\s\S]*`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a `xsd:whiteSpace` facet with `value="collapse"` and require a length of at least 1:

```
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <xs:element name="MoreThanWhiteSpaceElement">
    <xs:simpleType>
      <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
        <xs:whiteSpace value="collapse"/>
        <xs:minLength value="1"/>
      </xs:restriction>
    </xs:simpleType>
  </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

Comment: bah that solved my problem... works perfectly. I was not aware of that WhiteSpace tag. Thank you so much.

Comment: @SérgioAndaluzRamos Are you sure it is what you need? Because your `[^\s-]` requires a char other than whitespace *and* a hyphen, and this just requires a non-whitespace.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew: Since his examples and description relate only to whitespace, I believe it's safe to assume that the hyphen character in his attempted regex wasn't a literal part of his requirements.

Comment: I got the ideia from a post in a website, as of my reduced knowledge of regexs. I assumed it would do the trick. I did not test with the '-' I just wanted to rule out the cases described in my post here. But thanks for the help =)